# Handle one HTTP request from python with timeout

Tags: python, http, httpserver

I would like to write an application where the main thread start an HTTP server what have to wait for exactly one HTTP request for at most 10 seconds. The application have to be blocked until the request is received (and processed) or the timeout is exceeded.

I tried to use this code:

```
import BaseHTTPServer

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(s):
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title</title></head>")

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 8001), RequestHandler)
httpd.socket.settimeout(10)
httpd.handle_request()
```

The problem is that when the server receives a request, I get this error message:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51321)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 343, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 313, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately
```

If I remove the settimeout function, than I don't get this error, but I lost the timeout also. I tried to use the setblocking function too, but it destroy the effect of the settimeout.

How can I reach my goal?

PS.: I am using Python 2.7.2 on a 64-bit Windows 7

Comment: This works fine for me. How exactly do you issue the request?

Comment: Did you try with [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/499376-basehttpserver-with-socket-timeout/)?

Comment: @doukremt Just open http://localhost:8001 from a web browser

Comment: @Adriano I tried it with exactly the same code I posted here

Comment: @SqrtPi Yes, I guess so. I just suggested to try in **that** way...

Comment: Added system specification to the end of the question

Comment: @Adriano Sorry I haven't notice the link in your comment. Now I tried it out, but the timeout part isn't working for me (it is waiting for the request forever).

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the timeout is started only when a request is received, but what I need is to start the timeout, when I call the handle_request() method (or any other similar method).

Comment: An easy (and dirty) way (without **sublcassing `HTTPServer`** to add the timeout in `handle_request()`, see [this example](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/425210-simple-stoppable-server-using-socket-timeout/)) should be to create a timer to fire a **"dummy" request after 10 seconds** (for example using `xmlrpclib.Server`). It'll stop your server.

Comment: @Adriano Thank you. This approach is working well.